# accessing array object in json data format

Tags: javascript, json

```
postItem : [{
    id: 1,
    content: 'string',
    date: '1 Jan 2014',
    category: '1'

    },

    {
    id: 2,
    content: 'string2',
    date: '14 Jan 2014',
    category: '2'

    }]
```

postItem[0].content doesn't work to select the first array's content object. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `postItem` itself is a property, right?

Comment: it's an object, var data = {postItem,something else}

Comment: So it should be `data.postItem[0].content`

Comment: Make sure you've parsed the JSON, and aren't just trying to index a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must see that postItem is a property also. Supposing you have returned just one object in you JSON data, that is `data = {postItem, ... ,}` then to access postItem itself you must refer to the object that it belongs (in that case data).

So, if you do `postItem[0].content` you'll get an error, because `postItem` doesn't exist in that scope. Now, if you do `data.postItem[0].content` then you'll get correct, since you are accessing the variable where it really exists.